# Insertion Sort is Ridiculously fast for Reversed Order Array

Tags: python, arrays, insertion-sort

i am going to crazy. I have test case for 4 sorting algoritms (Bubble sort, selection sort, insertion sort and merge sort)

I tested with, Ordered array, reversed ordered array and random array. in every case, Insertion sort is Ridiculously fast. I tested with 1k, 5k, and 25k numbers. Insertion Sort must not be faster than merge sort? right? (by the way, Insertion sort is still faster with random number array case, insertion sort always fastest algorithm with my code. It must be wrong but what is wrong.. (I shared all my code)

```
Test Case for 1k Reversed Ordered Array: (in milis)

Bubble Sort run time: 512
Selection Sort run time: 154
Insertion Sort Run time: 1
Merge Sort run time: 19


test case for 5k reversed ordered number (in milis):

Bubble Sort run time: 11768
Selection Sort run time: 3613
Insertion Sort Run time: 4
Merge Sort run time: 100

Test Case for 25 k reversed ordered array

Bubble Sort run time: 303249
Selection Sort run time: 90469
Insertion Sort Run time: 20
Merge Sort run Zaman: 644
```

Here is my main code;

```
def CreateOrdered(Quantity):
    Array = []
    for i in range(Quantity):
        Array.append(i)
    return Array

def ReversedOrdered(Quantity):
    Array = []
    for i in range(Quantity):
        Array.append(Quantity-i)
    return Array

def RandomNumbers(Quantity):
    Array = []
    for i in range(Quantity):
        Array.append(randint(0,Quantity))
    return Array

Array = ReversedOrdered(1000)
ArrayCopyForSelection = Array
ArrayCopyForInsertion = Array
ArrayCopyForMerge = Array

BubbleSortStartTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
BubbleSort(Array)
BubbleSortStopTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print("Bubble Sort run time: " + str(BubbleSortStopTime-BubbleSortStartTime))
print(" ")

SelectionStartTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
SelectionSort(ArrayCopyForSelection)
SelectionStopTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print("Selection Sort run time: " + str(SelectionStopTime-SelectionStartTime))
print(" ")

InsertionStartTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
InsertionSort(ArrayCopyForInsertion)
InsertionStopTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print("Insertion Sort Run time: " + str(InsertionStopTime-InsertionStartTime))
print(" ")


MergeStartTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
Merge(ArrayCopyForMerge)
MergeStopTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print("Merge Sort run time: " + str(MergeStopTime-MergeStartTime))
```

and this is my sorting algorithms:

```
from random import seed
from random import randint
import time

def BubbleSort(Array):
    for i in range(len(Array)):
        flag = False
        for j in range(len(Array) - 1 - i):
            if Array[j] >  Array[j+1]:
                Array[j], Array[j+1] = Array[j+1], Array[j]
                flag = True
        if flag == False:
            break
    return Array

def SelectionSort(Array):
    for i in range(len(Array)):
        MinimumIndex = i
        for j in range(i+1,len(Array)):
            if Array[j] < Array[MinimumIndex]:
                MinimumIndex = j

        temp = Array[i]
        Array[i] = Array[MinimumIndex]
        Array[MinimumIndex] = temp
    return Array

def InsertionSort(Array):

    for i in range(1,len(Array)):
        key = Array[i]
        j = i - 1

        while key < Array[j] and j >= 0:
            Array[j+1] = Array[j]
            j = j - 1
        Array[j+1] = key
    return Array

def Merge(Array):
    if len(Array) > 1:
        mid = len(Array) // 2
        leftHalf = Array[:mid]
        rightHalf = Array[mid:]

        Merge(leftHalf)
        Merge(rightHalf)
        MergeSort(Array, leftHalf, rightHalf)

def MergeSort(Array, leftHalf, rightHalf):

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while i < len(leftHalf) and j < len(rightHalf):
        if leftHalf[i] < rightHalf[j]:
            Array[k] = leftHalf[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            Array[k] = rightHalf[j]
            j = j + 1
        k = k + 1

    while i < len(leftHalf):
        Array[k] = leftHalf[i]
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1

    while j < len(rightHalf):
        Array[k] = rightHalf[j]
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
```

Comment: Please follow Python naming conventions : variable, function in lowercase ;)

Comment: ah do you mean Camel case like "selectionSort" ?

Comment: There's a Python standard for naming styles called PEP-8, but a nice simple summary of them can be found [here](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-styles).

Answer (score 5):

Your test is wrong, because except for the first sorting you do (with `BubbleSort`), all the other sorting functions will get the already sorted array. This happens because you do not really *copy* the lists with this code:

```
Array = ReversedOrdered(1000)
ArrayCopyForSelection = Array
ArrayCopyForInsertion = Array
ArrayCopyForMerge = Array
```

These all reference the *same* list. So if `BubbleSort` sorts that list, it does not matter which of those variables you use: you get the *sorted* list.

You should do:

```
Array = ReversedOrdered(1000)
ArrayCopyForSelection = Array[:]
ArrayCopyForInsertion = Array[:]
ArrayCopyForMerge = Array[:]
```

NB: please consider starting your variable and function names with lower case. An initial upper case letter is commonly used for a class name.

NB2: don't use the name "Array" for what is a `list`. In Python an [Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is something more specific than just a `list`.

Comment: Oh My god, thank u. With my new test case with 5k reversed number is;

Bubble Sort run time: 11807

Selection Sort run time: 4121

Insertion Sort Run time: 8460

Merge Sort run time: 108

Comment: Yes, that looks more like it. Merge sort is the only one that has *O(nlogn)* time complexity (among your sort algorithms), so it explains why it completely outperforms the others with large input.